# Sharing Google Drive docs: some collaborators don't have access

Tags: google-drive

I have shared a document on Google Drive with several people. Some of those people get asked for a password when they click on the link to the document, but some don't.

How can I make it so that the collaborators all have access?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem and find that it is resolved by having those denied access to hit the "request an invitation." Once you invite them the second time it works. This happens every time I had collaborators without a Google account and has worked successfully.